# Error with onClick in NavigationView headerLayout Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

So, I have the NavigationView with this structure:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"

    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
```

It's on the main_activity.xml, the problem is when I try to make a TextView inside the layout within the headerLayout "@layout/nav_header" that has this structure:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/mat_bg1"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/background_floating_material_light"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/header_top_location_padding"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/nav_location"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/header_left_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/header_left_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/header_left_padding"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationSettings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="VALENCIA"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/accentColor"/>



    </LinearLayout> 
    [...]
```

The problem is that I can't make it to set any Clickable action when clicking on the TextView "locationSettings" inside that layout.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.nite.R.layout.activity_main);

    setToolbar();

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(com.nite.R.id.drawer_layout);

    final NavigationView menu = (NavigationView) findViewById(com.nite.R.id.nav_view);

    if (menu != null) {
        setupDrawerContent(menu);
    }

    final View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_header, menu, false);

    final TextView tv = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.locationSettings);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //DO you work here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey There",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            tv.setText("AAA");
        }

    });

        Fragment fragment = new HomeF();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(com.nite.R.id.main_content, fragment)
                .commit();

        //drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        setTitle(HomeF.ARG_SECTION_TITLE);


}
```

Any idea why?
By the way, I'm able to retrieve the getText from the TextView via Toast for example, so I'm referencing correctly the TextView, but being unable to set a clickable event...

Thanks.

Comment: could you take out all the "clickable=true"? The textview doesn't need that set. It will be clickable when you set the listener. There's rarely any reason to set those, and its possible the surrounding views eating clicks is causing the issue.

Comment: "Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey There",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);" doesn't work because you forget to call method ".show()" to actually show the toast. Apart from that, I don't see any obvious reasons, why it doesn't work (and yes, as mentioned above - remove "clickable" properties)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"`
and add the header view programmatically like this:

```
View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, navigationView, false);
navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```